# uploading a file to sharepoint using your phpSPO library

Tags: file-upload, php

I saw from one of your previous post that you are an author of phpSPO. I came across your phpSPO library earlier this month while trying to access sharepoint by php.

I went through your GitHub and saw the samples but with my limited knowledge on sharepoint, I only manage to get myself authenticated with sharepoint using my account, but I don't know how to say upload a file into sharepoint.

are you able to give me a simple example how to upload a file into sharepoint using your phpSPO library?

Comment: This implementation is very useful. Executed with no error. I have one question. I created a file and uploaded to sharepoint by giving my sharepoint URL. However, I cannot fine the file I uploaded. It does not show up in my folder on sharepoint. My question is what URL should I enter in setting? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The below example demonstrates how to upload a file using [SharePoint REST client for PHP](https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO):

```
$authCtx = new AuthenticationContext($webUrl);
$authCtx->acquireTokenForUser($userName,$password);
$ctx = new ClientContext($webUrl,$authCtx);

$localFilePath = "./data/user guide.docx";
$targetFileUrl = "Documents/user guide.docx";
$fileContent = file_get_contents($localFilePath);
File::saveBinary($ctx,$targetFileUrl,$fileContent);
print "File has been uploaded\r\n";
```

More examples that demonstrates how to perform operations with files could be found [here](https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO/blob/master/examples/file_examples.php)

Comment: I have tried this way of uploading this and using the uploadfile function but I am getting a success message but the file is not uploaded.

Comment: @wayzz, let me verify it, will get back to you

Comment: the error i am getting is this - The expression "web/lists(guid'dfeab1cd-904a-4816-9abf-0ad6ce31e630')/rootFolder/Files/add(overwrite=,url='test.pdf')" is not valid. . Hope this helps.

Comment: @wayzz, sure it was, thanks! Apparently it was an issue with resource url, the issue has been resolved in the latest version.

Comment: Thought so because going through the Sharepoint API manual I noticed that the url had been changed to GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/<Folder Name>'). Am i correct?

Comment: In this particular case it was caused by missing overwrite parameter, I was not able to detect it with unit tests, that is why your comment was very helpful :)

Comment: I see glad to help than :)